# SpigotMC java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(I)V

Tags: junit, bukkit, snakeyaml

I'm trying to use junit to test a Spigot plugin, but I get the following error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.yaml.snakeyaml.LoaderOptions.setMaxAliasesForCollections(I)V

at org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration.loadFromString(YamlConfiguration.java:56)
at org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration.load(FileConfiguration.java:160)
at org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(YamlConfiguration.java:217)
at tests.MessengerTests.conf(MessengerTests.java:24)
at tests.MessengerTests.msr(MessengerTests.java:19)
at tests.MessengerTests.testBasic(MessengerTests.java:30)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:42)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:263)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:68)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:47)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:231)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:60)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:222)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:300)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

I've tried searching for this error on DuckDuckGo, but haven't found a solution. I've tried updating spigot-api to 1.16.5, but get the same error. Is this a bug with Spigot, or could it be solved another way? I don't know what else to try here.

**MessengerTests.java**

```
package tests;

import me.rubyjay.bukkit.core.api.messenger.Messenger;
import me.rubyjay.bukkit.core.api.zconfig.ZConfigFile;
import org.bukkit.configuration.file.YamlConfiguration;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.StringReader;

public class MessengerTests {

    private static Messenger msr(ZConfigFile conf) {
        return new Messenger(new TestModule(), conf);
    }

    private static Messenger msr(String contents) {
        return msr(conf(contents));
    }

    private static ZConfigFile conf(String contents) {
        StringReader reader = new StringReader(contents);
        YamlConfiguration conf = YamlConfiguration.loadConfiguration(reader);
        return ZConfigFile.wrap(new File("test.yml"), conf);
    }

    @Test
    public void testBasic() {
        Messenger msr = msr("hello: '&9Hello&7, &2World&d!!'").cfg("hello");
        Assert.assertEquals("§9Hello§7, §2World§d!!", msr.outString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testLink() {
        Messenger msr = msr("test: 'If you like cheese, [click here](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=cheese), but not here.'").cfg("test");
        Assert.assertEquals("§9Hello§7, §2World§d!!", msr.outComponent());
    }

//    @Test
//    public void testData() {
//        Messenger msr = msr("hello: '&9Hello&7, &2World&d!! '");
//        Assert.assertEquals("§9Hello§7, §2World§d!!", msr.getString());
//    }
//
//    @Test
//    public void testList() {
//        Messenger msr = msr("{\"cmd\":{\"list\":{\"head\":\"&9--- Header ---\",\"item\":\"&b - <item>\",\"foot\":\"&9--------------\"}}}");
//        Assert.assertEquals("§9Hello§7, §2World§d!!", msr.getString());
//    }

    @Test
    public void testMissingConfigPathAbsolute() {
        Messenger msr = msr("").cfg("this.message.does.not.exist");
        Assert.assertEquals("§cMissing config message: this.message.does.not.exist", msr.outString());
    }

    @Test
    public void testMissingConfigPathRelative() {
        Messenger msr = msr("{\"this\":{\"message\":{\"exists\":\"but we're not using it.\"}}}")
                .path("this.message").cfg(".does.not.exist");
        Assert.assertEquals("§cMissing config message: this.message.does.not.exist", msr.outString());
    }

}
```

**ZConfigFile.java**

```
package me.rubyjay.bukkit.core.api.zconfig;

import org.bukkit.configuration.file.FileConfiguration;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author Ruby jay
 */
public class ZConfigFile extends ZConfigWrapper {

    private final File file;

    private ZConfigFile(File file, FileConfiguration config) {
        super(config);
        this.file = file;
    }

    @Override
    public FileConfiguration unwrap() {
        return (FileConfiguration)super.unwrap();
    }

    public static ZConfigFile wrap(File file, FileConfiguration config) {
        if (file == null || config == null) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return new ZConfigFile(file, config);
        }
    }

    /**
     * @return the file
     */
    public File getFile() {
        return file;
    }

    public boolean save() {
        try {
            unwrap().save(file);
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZConfigFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to save zconfig " + file.getName(), ex);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public boolean backup() {
        String name = file.getName();

        try {
            Date date = new Date();
            SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd.HH-mm-ss");
            name += "." + dateFormat.format(date) + ".old";

            unwrap().save(new File(file.getParentFile(), name));
            return true;
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ZConfigFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, "Failed to backup zconfig " + name, ex);
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**ZConfigWrapper.java**

```
package me.rubyjay.bukkit.core.api.zconfig;

import org.bukkit.Color;
import org.bukkit.OfflinePlayer;
import org.bukkit.configuration.Configuration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.ConfigurationOptions;
import org.bukkit.configuration.ConfigurationSection;
import org.bukkit.configuration.MemoryConfiguration;
import org.bukkit.configuration.serialization.ConfigurationSerializable;
import org.bukkit.inventory.ItemStack;
import org.bukkit.util.Vector;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Contract;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull;
import org.jetbrains.annotations.Nullable;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Objects;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * @inheritDoc
 *
 * @author Ruby jay
 */
public class ZConfigWrapper implements ZConfig {

    private final ConfigurationSection config;
    private String rootPath;

    protected ZConfigWrapper(ConfigurationSection config) {
        this.config = config;
    }

    public ConfigurationSection unwrap() {
        return config;
    }

    public static ZConfig newEmpty() {
        return new ZConfigWrapper(new MemoryConfiguration());
    }

    @Contract("null -> null")
    public static ZConfig wrap(ConfigurationSection conf) {
        if (conf == null) {
            return null;
        } else if (conf instanceof ZConfig) {
            return (ZConfig) conf;
        } else {
            return new ZConfigWrapper(conf);
        }
    }

    // (Redacted) Implemented methods
    // Example:
    @NotNull
    @Override
    public Set<String> getKeys(boolean deep) {
        return config.getKeys(deep);
    }
    // End Example

    @NotNull
    @Override
    public ZConfig getRoot() {
        return ZConfigWrapper.wrap(Objects.requireNonNull(config.getRoot()));
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return getValues().toString();
    }
}
```

**Zonfig** is an interface that extends `org.bukkit.configuration.Configuration` and adds a lot of custom methods.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>me.rubyjay.bukkit</groupId>
    <artifactId>ruby-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>RubyCore</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <minecraft.version>1.16.5</minecraft.version>
        <minecraft_version>1_16_R1</minecraft_version>
        <spigot.version>1.16.5-R0.1-SNAPSHOT</spigot.version>
    </properties>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spigotmc-repo</id>
            <url>https://hub.spigotmc.org/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>vault-repo</id>
            <url>http://nexus.hc.to/content/repositories/pub_releases</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>sk89q-repo</id>
            <url>http://maven.sk89q.com/repo/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>dmulloy2-repo</id>
            <url>http://repo.dmulloy2.net/nexus/repository/public/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>placeholderapi</id>
            <url>http://repo.extendedclip.com/content/repositories/placeholderapi/</url>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>codemc-repo</id>
            <url>https://repo.codemc.org/repository/maven-public/</url>
            <layout>default</layout>
        </repository>
        <repository>
            <id>skullcreator-repo</id>
            <url>https://dl.bintray.com/deanveloper/SkullCreator</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <dependencies>
        <!--<editor-fold desc="org.jetbrains:annotations">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jetbrains</groupId>
            <artifactId>annotations</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="junit">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="ninja.leaping.configurate">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ninja.leaping.configurate</groupId>
            <artifactId>configurate-gson</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ninja.leaping.configurate</groupId>
            <artifactId>configurate-hocon</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ninja.leaping.configurate</groupId>
            <artifactId>configurate-yaml</artifactId>
            <version>3.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="net.sourceforge.htmlunit">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.sourceforge.htmlunit</groupId>
            <artifactId>htmlunit</artifactId>
            <version>2.30</version>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->

        <!--<editor-fold desc="org.spigotmc">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>
            <artifactId>spigot-api</artifactId>
            <version>${spigot.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--<dependency>-->
            <!--<groupId>org.spigotmc</groupId>-->
            <!--<artifactId>minecraft-server</artifactId>-->
            <!--<version>${minecraft.version}-SNAPSHOT</version>-->
            <!--<type>jar</type>-->
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
        <!--</dependency>-->
        <!--</editor-fold>-->

        <!--<editor-fold desc="net.milkbowl.vault">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>net.milkbowl.vault</groupId>
            <artifactId>VaultAPI</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="me.clip:placeholderapi">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>me.clip</groupId>
            <artifactId>placeholderapi</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="de.tr7zw:item-nbt-api">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>de.tr7zw</groupId>
            <artifactId>item-nbt-api</artifactId>
            <version>LATEST</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="com.deanveloper:skullcreator">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>dev.dbassett</groupId>
            <artifactId>skullcreator</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->

        <!--<editor-fold desc="com.sk89q:worldedit">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldedit</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
        <!--<editor-fold desc="com.sk89q.worldguard">-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard-core</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sk89q.worldguard</groupId>
            <artifactId>worldguard-legacy</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sk89q</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commandbook</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <!--</editor-fold>-->
    </dependencies>

    <!--<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="build">-->
    <build>
        <defaultGoal>clean package</defaultGoal>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>test</testSourceDirectory>
        <finalName>${project.name}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.0</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <minimizeJar>true</minimizeJar>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
                <configuration>
                    <relocations>
                        <relocation>
                            <pattern>de.tr7zw.changeme.nbtapi</pattern>
                            <shadedPattern>de.tr7zw.nbtapi.rubycore</shadedPattern>
                        </relocation>
                    </relocations>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.2</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-resources</id>
                        <!-- here the phase you need -->
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>libraries/</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <!-- Get main artifact -->
                                    <directory>target</directory>
                                    <!-- Don't filter binary files -->
                                    <filtering>false</filtering>
                                    <includes>
                                        <include>${project.build.finalName}.jar</include>
                                    </includes>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.6.0</version>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>Distribution script</id>
                        <phase>install</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>exec</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <executable>bash</executable>
                            <commandlineArgs>/home/ruby/AppData/minecraft/server/bin/mcdist</commandlineArgs>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>resources</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
            </resource>
        </resources>
    </build>
    <!--</editor-fold>-->

</project>
```

Comment: I believe your `ZConfigFile` might be useful here, especially your `wrap` method.

Comment: I added `ZConfigFile` as well as `ZConfigWrapper`, and explained what `ZConfig` is.

Answer (score 0):

So I've had this happen before on my IDE, mostly when I was editing the main projects API. And then going into the second project, not syncing the maven repo between it, and then compiling it, since I added/changed a class file in the API, the class "technically" doesn't exist, because it's now using different methods. This might not be helpful, cause I had to both sync and restart my IDE multiple times to fix the issue. But I got it working after a while.